# how to use sharepoint in winforms application

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer

I want to use sharpoint in my winform application

any one give me suggestion how i use sharpoint in winform and i want to access all the properties of outlook using sharepoint in my winform application

how it is possible

give me any refrence site for learn more about sharpoint with winforms

Comment: Please clarify how you wish to interact with Outlook?

Answer (score 2):

Everything you need to know to get started is on [MSDN, under the Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094%28office.14%29.aspx). This only works with SharePoint 2010, however. For SharePoint 2007, you will have to interact with SharePoint via its [web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862916%28v=office.12%29.aspx).